# C++: call function template from superclass

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, c++11, virtual

As virtual templates methods are not allowed in C++11, is there a workaround to call a subclass method from superclass?
I have some classes (part of visitor design). They are algorithms to traverse a custom tree.

Speaking in "visitor terms": my visitors are algorithms to traverse the tree and the elements are the iterators of my custom `tree<T>` type.

In short: I need a pure virtual method that accepts any `type_of_iterator<T>` without using curiously recurring template pattern (`iterator_visitor<T>` must be the same for every concrete visitor).

```
// this is the virtual visitor
template <typename T>
class iterator_visitor {
    // increments FORWARD regardless the  iterator verse
    template <typename It> virtual void increment(const It&) const = 0;
    // increments BACKWARD regardless the iterator verse
    template <typename It> virtual void decrement(const It&) const = 0; 
    void visit_increment(iterator<T>&) const;
    void visit_decrement(iterator<T>&) const;
    // same for const_iterator<T>, reverse_iterator<T> and const_reverse_iterator<T>
};

// concrete iterator example
class pre_order final : public iterator_visitor<T> {
    template <typename Iterator> void increment(const Iterator&) const override;
    template <typename Iterator> void decrement(const Iterator&) const override;
};
```

My requirements are:

- I need a unique interface to refer to the visitor (no CRTP) and call from this interface `visit_increment(...)`, `visit_decrement(...)` methods. (`tree<T>` has a `iterator_visitor<T>&` attribute)
- I don't want to use void pointer because it feels somehow dirty to me.
- It must be thread safe.

Comment: Anything that changes something else is implicitly **not** thread safe. You will need to throw a mutex, conditional or an atomic in if you want both.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a ungeneric base class for your function parameter, everything else does make no sense and suggests an design flaw.